# Exchange 2013 Is it possible to use message rules to change from email address of emails send to a group of users?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I do not want to change the `from` address for all messages, only for the ones sent to a small group.

For example: Normally `notification@domain.com` is sent email to `users@domain.com`.  What I need to do is if `notification@domain.com` is sending an email to `bob@domain.com`, then change the `"from"` to `notification@otherdomain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transport rules can't modify the sender address, regardless of which condition you specify for triggering a rule. So no, this is not possible.

More information:

- [Transport rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351127(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [Transport rule conditions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638183(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [Transport rule actions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998315(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the sender's address is possible in Exchange 2007, 2010 and 2013 by using this third party tool: http://www.codetwo.com/preview/exchange-rules-pro/email-address-rewriting

However from Exchange 2016 (and newer) you can rewrite the sender's address in Exchange without the need for 3rd party tools. Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124347(v=exchg.160).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about header rewriting. That is only possible natively with the Edge role. However there are third party tools that can do header rewriting for you.

Simon.